# Polls with respective comments?

Tags: comments, poll

I am using [wp-polls](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-polls/) plugin. It's working fine. Instead I need some more things in this which are :

1. I want to use comments with each poll. (I think this can be possible
   when adding A New Poll, A New Page will generate) so I can get
   comments on that Poll via that Page.
2. When I click on Polls Archive link then all Polls are visible it's
   fine but I want to see their respective comments on that Polls
   Archive Page.
3. How to get latest Poll with it's comments ?

Please give me any solution either with this plugin or any other way to manage the Polls with respective comments.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see a way to do it with any existing plugins.

Probably the best thing to do would be to modify the plugin so that in the short code you could put "post=186" where 186 corresponds to the number of the page that you're posting it on. And then modify the output of the Polls Archive to show the comments from that page.

Comment: Can you provide sample code for the solution?